# replacing numeric values in excel with word

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet ( a small part of it):

yes yes

yes 17.00

yes #N/A

yes 19.00

yes 24.00

yes 33.00

I want to replace all the numeric values with "yes".
I tried using isnumber, find&replace. But I could not do it for all the cells. Can someone help me here? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are the numeric values **constants** or the result of **formulas**??

Comment: Numeric values are constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numeric values are Constants, then run:

```
Sub YesMan()
    ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(2, 1).Value = "yes"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Where shall I run this?

Comment: @kvc_bioinfo - The same place where you *'tried using isnumber, find&replace'*.